# In Google Contacts: Google+ Title Autocompletion not pushed to Contacts API

Tags: google-contacts-api

When adding google contacts, the contact title is entered automatically if the email is linked to a google+ account, see: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1004639/stackoverflow/googlecontacts.png

When this happens, the contact title in the google contacts ip is an empty string. Although the title is visible in the web app:

```
"title": { "type": "text",  "$t": "" }
```

Does someone know a possibility to get this title in the google contacts api? Or does the google contacts api result contain a link to G+ which I didn't discover yet?